# how to remove a set of digits from string in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm working on an htaccess file in Google Sheets. Now I have all these new URL's with a product ID in it. Like: `http://sample.com/catogory/22265/product/` That number (in this case `22265`) is different from every other URL, as it is a unique ID.

Is there a way to remove that group of digits including 1 slash (`/`) from the string? So like this: `http://sample.com/catogory/product/`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Something like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\d+\/","")
```

... where A1 has the url with the product ID.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A; "[^\D+]"; ); "//"; "/"); ":/"; "://")
```

---

or array fx variant:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A; 
 "[^\D+]"; ); "//"; "/"); ":/"; "://"))
```

[image: 0]

---

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A; "\d+\/"; ))
```

[image: 0]

### _____________________________________________________________

### an alternative would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A1:A; "/")); "select Col1,Col2,Col3,"&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; "Col"&ROW(
 INDIRECT("A5:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1:A; "/"))))); 0));;999^99))); " "; "/"); ":/"; "://"))
```

[image]

Comment: i gave it a go, but clearly i'm doing something wrong? I got a parse error => https://i.imgur.com/K14QkPq.jpg

Comment: Ow wait i got it now! Thanks!!  I need to put the formula above the column. That way it works